# Can't access URL of created Pop Up window

Tags: javascript, html, window

I'm creating a new window and opening it on a new pop up window

```
 var win = window.open(varforURl,"Login to Spot",'width=800, height=600');
```

On my next line I'm trying to get the URL of the window I just created and the pop up window is still opened.

```
console.log(win.document.URL);
```

What I expect to see is:

```
https://accounts.spotify.com/en/authorize?....
```

(This is the Url I passed with a variable, and it is in fact displayed on the page)

However, on my console I get `about:blank`

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can get the url for the window I created?

Comment: If it is not the same origin, you are not allowed. Look in the console and you will see an access denied error

Comment: @mplungjan
Thanks for sending this. I did research , but was using incorrect terms and/or keywords.

Comment: :) I took the terms from your title. "Get URL of Popup"

Answer (score -1):

`win.location.href` 
Should do the trick

Comment: Likely access denied - location.href and [document.URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/URL) will return the same

Comment: I get the same thing here.
about:blank